# How to extend glassfish jaxb NamespacePrefixMapper and set as a Marshaller property

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, java-17

I am using Spring boot 3 with Java 17 and setting the com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper property as below,

```
  final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(t.getClass());
                final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
                marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespacePrefixMapper());
```

MyNamespacePrefixMapper class looks like below,

```
import org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;

public class MyNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {

        if (MyConstant.NAMESPACE_MY_SERVICE.equals(namespaceUri)) {
            return "tos";
        } 
        return suggestion;

    }
}
```

I have dependencies below,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am getting a property exception saying, `jakarta.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: com.example.MyNamespacePrefixMapper@4bd4d5fa`

What am i missing here?

Comment: Do you generate you java from xsd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property name changed from `"com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper"` to `org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl#PREFIX_MAPPER` which equals `"org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper"` in jaxb3 and jaxb4.

Please use new value for property `"org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper"` or associated constant.

You can also try to use [Namespace Prefix XJC Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Namespace-Prefix-Plugin) in order to make it automatic from XSD to JAVA generation code.